# Getting all global variables from compiled file (linux). How to separate static from const?

Tags: linux, global-variables, nm

So, I have something really strange here.

For example I have 2 .cpp files, one of them containing

```
const std::string DICTIONARY_DEFAULT = "blah";
const std::string ADDTODICTIONARY_DEFAULT = "blah";
const std::string BUTTONS = "blah";
```

and the second one with

```
static int  x1;
static int  NewY1, NewY2, NewX1, NewX2;
```

Both fragments are in the global variables section.
I need to print the global static variables (for example), but ignore constants. In `nm` output they're looking absolutely identical (b-type for every case, which means uninitialized local scope symbol). Is there any way to separate this cases automatically using only linux utilities (grep, regexps and so on are perfectly okay)?

Comment: If you have the source, why are you looking for them in object files?

Comment: Because there are around 5k .cpp files and I need to get global vars (not const) from all of them.

Answer (score 1):

***Short answer***: There is actually no way to do it in every case

***Long answer***: Take a look at the SYMBOL TABLE using 'objdump -x file.o'. You can see that all global variables, both static and const, are allocated into a section called .bss. A section called .rodata also exists and it is, generally speaking, used to store const data. Unfortunately, in your case you are declaring two const std::string objects. Those objects are initialized by invoking their constructor before the 'main' function is run. Still, the initialization of their fields happens at run-time and so they are only 'logically' const, and not really const.

The compiler has no choice but to allocate them into the .bss section with all other globals. If you add the following line

```
const int willBeInRoData = 42;
```

You will find that its symbol will be in the .rodata section and so it will be distinguishable from the other global integers.

NOTE: duped from [Try to find global variables from compiled files. The program can't distinguish constants from global variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684683/try-to-find-global-variables-from-compiled-files-the-program-cant-distinguish/13687338#13687338) since the question is exactly the same.