# Try to find global variables from compiled files. The program can't distinguish constants from global variables.

Tags: c++, unix, global-variables

Good Day! I'm trying to find the decision for a long time.

My problem is:

For example I have 2 .cpp files, one of them containing

```
const std::string DICTIONARY_DEFAULT = "blah";
const std::string ADDTODICTIONARY_DEFAULT = "blah";
const std::string BUTTONS = "blah";
```

and the second one with

```
static int  x1;
static int  NewY1, NewY2, NewX1, NewX2;
```

Both fragments are in the global variables section. I need to print the global static variables (for example), but ignore constants. In nm output they're looking absolutely identical (b-type for every case, which means uninitialized local scope symbol). Is there any way to separate this cases automatically using only linux utilities (grep, regexps and so on are perfectly okay)?

MY TASK FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING:

There is a program in C++, the main task is to find and to withdraw the list of global variables.
Input data looks like archives with lots of .cpp files. Every .cpp file is syntactically correct program in C++ (It Must successfully compiled using compilier GNU C++ and Microsoft Visual C++).
For every file from the archive I must output in separate string the name of the file and the list of global variables, like in the example:

Output Data :

```
000000.cpp ancestor ansv cost graph M N p qr query u
000001.cpp
000002.cpp
000003.cpp
000004.cpp
000005.cpp
000006.cpp
000007.cpp edge tree
```

Comment: do you want to parse a CPP file or a compiled library? In first case you need a simple C++ parser (many IDE already have one you can look at source code of opensource IDEs like Code::blocks). Anyway if you need only that, should not be hard make your parser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

finding global variables is a 'subject' of [this clang tutorial](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html) -- in this tutorial author did it 'just for fun', but you may add some code to do exactly what you need... (btw, it is not so hard as one may guess :))

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** There is actually no way to do it in every case

**Long answer:** Take a look at the SYMBOL TABLE using 'objdump -x file.o'. You can see that all global variables, both static and const, are allocated into a section called .bss. A section called .rodata also exists and it is, generally speaking, used to store const data. Unfortunately, in your case you are declaring two const std::string objects. Those objects are initialized by invoking their constructor before the 'main' function is run. Still, the initialization of their fields happens at run-time and so they are only 'logically' const, and not really const.

The compiler has no choice but to allocate them into the .bss section with all other globals.
If you add the following line

```
const int willBeInRoData = 42;
```

You will find that its symbol will be in the .rodata section and so it will be distinguishable from the other global integers.